# How to implement a toggle switch inside a nested array in a FieldArray in Formik?

Tags: toggle, formik

quite new to Formik and FieldArrays. Any help is much appreciated.

The problem:

I have a FieldArray which renders a list of objects each having some Fields, a deleteCurrentObject and a addNewObject button . I have successfully implemented the functionality of adding new object and deleting the current one. What I need to implement and still have not found a solution to this is a toggle switch for each of the nested objects inside this FieldArray that will change the state of each object in the parent FieldArray. To be more specific, I need to be able to disable one or more of the Fields (inputs) depending on the status of the toggler. For this reason I have included in the ionitialValues of the FieldArray an isEditing boolean property, with the hope of switching its state from true to false. I have managed to do this with the help of setFieldValue or directly but the problem with this approach is that once the isEditing value of each object inside the FieldArray is changing, the change is not propagated down.

In any case , any indication of how to implement a toggle switch inside each object of a FieldArray is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you already did so it's easier to understand your problem and also create a solution that fix your problem. Without any code, I'm not able to understand your problem correctly or understand how you are using the `FieldArray` and what is not working.

Comment: This is a link to a draft version : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-https-2wf9e?file=/src/SomeForm.js

What I need to do is to find a way to toggle the isEditingFee property of the Field array from true to false by clicking on the button Confirm, so I can get the Fields disabled. If I manage to implement this mechanism onClick of the Confirm button I will then create another Edit button toggle the isEditingFee back to false if the user wants to ammend the fee prices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: codesandbox.io/s/nifty-https-2wf9e?file=/src/SomeForm.js